# Tesla GPU Usage

Tags: windows-server-2008, gpgpu, nvidia, tesla

In my machine three GPUs are connected.ie, Tesla M2090. I want to get the usage of that GPUs. There is a tool called NVIDIA SMI which show shows the GPU usage. But when i tried to run the Option nvidia-smi.exe -d (I want to know memory and GPU Utilization). Please help

Driver version : 275.65
OS: Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: "But when you tried to run...." Did you leave something out there?

Answer (score 2):

Yes I got it by following

https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/cuda/files/CUDADownloads/NVML_cuda5/nvidia-smi.4.304.pdf

I give the command as follows

```
nvidia-smi.exe -q -d MEMORY,UTILIZATION
```